# Optimizing Memory in Haskell, pipes, attoparsec, and containers

Tags: haskell, optimization, haskell-pipes

I'm trying to further optimize my pipes-attoparsec parser and storage, but having trouble getting memory usage any lower.

Given account-parser.hs

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}

import Protolude hiding (for)

import Data.Hashable
import Data.IntMap.Strict (IntMap)
import Data.Vector (Vector)
import Pipes
import Pipes.Parse
import Pipes.Safe (MonadSafe, runSafeT)
import qualified Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8 as AB
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as IM
import qualified Data.Vector as Vector
import qualified Pipes.Attoparsec as PA
import qualified Pipes.ByteString as PB
import qualified Pipes.Safe.Prelude as PSP

-- accountid|account-name|contractid|code

data AccountLine = AccountLine {
    _accountId         :: !ByteString,
    _accountName       :: !ByteString,
    _accountContractId :: !ByteString,
    _accountCode       :: !Word32
    } deriving (Show)

type MapCodetoAccountIdIdx = IntMap Int

data Accounts = Accounts {
    _accountIds   :: !(Vector ByteString),
    _cache        :: !(IntMap Int),
    _accountCodes :: !MapCodetoAccountIdIdx
    } deriving (Show)


parseAccountLine :: AB.Parser AccountLine
parseAccountLine = AccountLine <$>
    getSubfield <* delim <*>
    getSubfield <* delim <*>
    getSubfield <* delim <*>
    AB.decimal <* AB.endOfLine
    where getSubfield = AB.takeTill (== '|')
          delim = AB.char '|'

--

aempty :: Accounts
aempty = Accounts Vector.empty IM.empty IM.empty

aappend :: Accounts -> AccountLine -> Accounts
aappend (Accounts ids a2i cps) (AccountLine aid an cid cp) =
    case IM.lookup (hash aid) a2i of
        Nothing -> Accounts
                (Vector.snoc ids (toS aid))
                (IM.insert (hash aid) (length ids) a2i)
                (IM.insert (fromIntegral cp) (length ids) cps)
        Just idx -> Accounts ids a2i (IM.insert (fromIntegral cp) idx cps)

foldAccounts :: (Monad m) => Parser AccountLine m Accounts
foldAccounts = foldAll aappend aempty identity

readByteStringFile :: (MonadSafe m) => FilePath -> Producer' ByteString m ()
readByteStringFile file = PSP.withFile file ReadMode PB.fromHandle

accountLines :: Text -> MonadSafe m => Producer AccountLine m (Either (PA.ParsingError, Producer ByteString m ()) ())
accountLines filename = PA.parsed parseAccountLine (readByteStringFile (toS filename))


main :: IO ()
main = do
    [filename] <- getArgs
    x <- runSafeT $ runEffect $ Pipes.Parse.evalStateT foldAccounts (accountLines (toS filename))

    print $ sizes x

sizes :: Accounts -> (Int, Int, Int)
sizes (Accounts aid xxx acp) = (Vector.length aid, IM.size xxx, IM.size acp)
```

Compiled with GHC 8.0.2 (`stack ghc -- -O2 -rtsopts -threaded -Wall account-parser.hs`)

I can't get the memory usage any lower. I have to do fast look ups hence the IntMaps. The file is around 20 MB (and not efficient). Most of the data should be able to fit in 5 MB.

```
$ ./account-parser /tmp/accounts +RTS -s
(5837,5837,373998)
   1,631,040,680 bytes allocated in the heap
     221,765,464 bytes copied during GC
      41,709,048 bytes maximum residency (13 sample(s))
       2,512,560 bytes maximum slop
              82 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      2754 colls,     0 par    0.105s   0.142s     0.0001s    0.0002s
  Gen  1        13 colls,     0 par    0.066s   0.074s     0.0057s    0.0216s

  TASKS: 4 (1 bound, 3 peak workers (3 total), using -N1)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.324s  (  0.298s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.171s  (  0.216s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.005s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.495s  (  0.520s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    5,026,660,297 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  65.5% of total user, 58.4% of total elapsed

gc_alloc_block_sync: 0
whitehole_spin: 0
gen[0].sync: 0
gen[1].sync: 0
```

And the profile:

[image]

Comment: I'm not an expert in this, so take the following with the requisite quantity of salt: It looks like arrays are taking up most of your heap. How many unique accounts are there in your input file? Every time you encounter a new account, `Vector.snoc` has to copy the whole array and make the old one into garbage. Have you tried loading your account IDs into a data structure with a cheap 'add' (eg `[]`, `Seq`, or some variety of mutable growable array)?

Comment: Following up on that, I think just using a list and `fromList . reverse` after folding would help. Vectors are not designed for efficient cons or snoc.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I tried `[]` but that raised the memory a little (~10-20MB depending on using `-c` or not. I left a comment with what is likely the best I can do

Answer (score 0):

If I,

- remove the intermediate look up cache
- use a `HashMap Text (Set Word32)`
- turn on in place compaction `+RTS -c`

I can get the total memory down to 34 MB, but my lookups now go to O(n). This is likely the best I'm going to get.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}

import           Protolude hiding (for)

import qualified Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8 as AB
import           Data.HashMap.Strict (HashMap)
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HashMap
import           Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import           Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Attoparsec as PA
import qualified Pipes.ByteString as PB
import           Pipes.Parse
import           Pipes.Safe (MonadSafe, runSafeT)
import qualified Pipes.Safe.Prelude as PSP

-- accountid|account-name|contractid|code

data AccountLine = AccountLine {
    _accountId         :: !ByteString,
    _accountName       :: !ByteString,
    _accountContractId :: !ByteString,
    _accountCode       :: !Word32
    } deriving (Show)


newtype Accounts = Accounts (HashMap Text (Set Word32))
                 deriving (Show)

parseAccountLine :: AB.Parser AccountLine
parseAccountLine = AccountLine <$>
    getSubfield <* delim <*>
    getSubfield <* delim <*>
    getSubfield <* delim <*>
    AB.decimal <* AB.endOfLine
    where getSubfield = AB.takeTill (== '|')
          delim = AB.char '|'

--

aempty :: Accounts
aempty = Accounts HashMap.empty

aappend :: Accounts -> AccountLine -> Accounts
aappend (Accounts cps) (AccountLine aid an cid cp) =
    case HashMap.lookup (toS aid) cps of
        Nothing  -> Accounts (HashMap.insert (toS aid) (Set.singleton cp) cps)
        Just value -> Accounts (HashMap.update (\codes -> Just (Set.insert cp value)) (toS aid) cps)

foldAccounts :: (Monad m) => Parser AccountLine m Accounts
foldAccounts = foldAll aappend aempty identity

readByteStringFile :: (MonadSafe m) => FilePath -> Producer' ByteString m ()
readByteStringFile file = PSP.withFile file ReadMode PB.fromHandle

accountLines :: Text -> MonadSafe m => Producer AccountLine m (Either (PA.ParsingError, Producer ByteString m ()) ())
accountLines filename = PA.parsed parseAccountLine (readByteStringFile (toS filename))


main :: IO ()
main = do
    [filename] <- getArgs
    x <- runSafeT $ runEffect $ Pipes.Parse.evalStateT foldAccounts (accountLines (toS filename))

    print $ sizes x

    -- print x
    print $ lookupAccountFromCode x 254741
    print $ lookupAccountFromCode x 196939


sizes :: Accounts -> Int
sizes (Accounts acp) = HashMap.size acp

lookupAccountFromCode :: Accounts -> Word32 -> Maybe Text
lookupAccountFromCode (Accounts accts) cp = do
    let f a k v = bool a (Just k) (Set.member cp v)
    HashMap.foldlWithKey' f Nothing accts
```

And running

```
$ ./account-parser /tmp/accounts +RTS -s -c
5837
Just "1-PCECJ5"
Just "AANA-76KOUU"
   1,652,177,904 bytes allocated in the heap
      83,767,440 bytes copied during GC
      17,563,800 bytes maximum residency (18 sample(s))
         751,144 bytes maximum slop
              34 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      3083 colls,     0 par    0.058s   0.069s     0.0000s    0.0002s
  Gen  1        18 colls,     0 par    0.115s   0.151s     0.0084s    0.0317s

  TASKS: 4 (1 bound, 3 peak workers (3 total), using -N1)

  SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.002s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.263s  (  0.289s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.173s  (  0.219s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.009s  (  0.008s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.445s  (  0.518s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    6,286,682,587 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  61.0% of total user, 57.4% of total elapsed

gc_alloc_block_sync: 0
whitehole_spin: 0
gen[0].sync: 0
gen[1].sync: 0
```